# Cannot get email from query string

Tags: php, email, url

I'm having trouble getting an email address from `$_GET`. 
Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $eadd = $_GET['email'];
    echo("<p>Please check your inbox on your email $eadd.</p>");
?>
```

I went to this link:

```
http://localhost/file.php?email=myemail@company.com
```

Yet the output is only:

```
Please check your inbox on your email .
```

**EDIT**

Here's my complete code :

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";
//Get link posted info's needed

//Email
$eadd = $_GET['email'];

 $from = "OtakuJam Registration <no-reply@comp.com>";
 $to = " $unick < $eadd >";
 $subject = "Thank you for registering";
 $body = "Dear $unick ,
\n    Thank you for registering to OtakuJam. To activate your account, \n
    ";

 $host = "mail.srv.com";
 $username = "name@comp.com";
 $password = "mypass";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
 'username' => $username,
 'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Please check your inbox on your email $eadd.</p>");
  }
?>
```

`Please ignore the $unick there, also the mail won't send unless i put an email on the code instead of < $eadd >

Comment: this code work correctly, maybe you must check if is set the get var

Comment: Try adding some debugging - put `var_dump($_GET)` inside your PHP code to see what it's actually being passed.

Comment: FYI, Dont forget to XSS protect `$eadd` before outputting

Comment: This is an XSS hole, you have to wrap `$eadd` inside at least `htmlspecialchars` to avoid

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè Your name hurts my eyes!

Comment: This code is working as written. If you want to send an email, you need to add a statement to do that.

Comment: no I think he wants to know why `$eadd` is empty although we have `http://localhost/file.php?email=myemail@company.com`

Comment: code looks about right, printr($_GET) or var_dump $_GET array

Comment: I just checked it on my local server and it is working completely fine. I copied pasted your code. Its fine dude. Still if it is not working then use print_r($_GET) to see if $_GET array has data or not. If it has data,  then try to use  echo("<p>Please check your inbox on your email ".$eadd.".</p> ");   But again your code is fine and it is working. Please double check it.

Comment: Please check my post again. I added my complete code.

Comment: `echo "<p>Please check your inbox on your email". $eadd.".</p>";` ???

Comment: please also check my $to = since it doesn't work with the syntax i made above.

Comment: doesnt this `$to = $unick . "<" . $eadd . ">";`  work???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turning my $to syntax to $to = $unick . "<" . $eadd . ">"; as @Charlie gave me helped me. Also to those who told me to use ".$variable.". to my echo helped. thanks